# How to upsert from old and new excel sheets by some providers that are very large in size(1GB -5GB)?

Tags: sql-server, excel, database, ssis, upsert

I have to insert or update data came from new Excel Files into SQL Server database, by comparing new excel file with old one having same structure, but the files have 150 columns itself and the size is between (1GB and 5GB),

Normally I am exporting all the file data into a staging table and comparing them with original SQL tables. But the problem is that it is taking too much time probably more than half the day.

And even though this excel sheet is having a unique column (so I can insert the data using a SSIS package), considering update scenario where any of these 150 columns at any rows can be changed I am having a headache there.

Comment: You need to use below transformations.

1. Data Conversion
2. Sort
3. Merge Join
4. Conditional Split
5. OLEDB Destination - for insert new record
6. OLEDB Command - for update existing record

Search key words for the above
ssis update or insert based on primary key
how to insert new and update existing records using ssis

Comment: Hi @JIKEN ,I am aware of the steps up to 5 as inserting part is quite clear,  But could you be more specific about the update scenario;  Do I have to check Excel/OLEDB source with the excel file all columns by some query, or is there any other means of doing so?

Comment: Please check this links for steps. 1. [Insert and Update table data using Merge Join](http://www.learnmsbitutorials.net/insert-update-data-using-merge-join-ssis.php)  2. [Sync Table Data Using Merge Join](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5082/synchronize-table-data-using-a-merge-join-in-ssis/)